# How do i begin a statement just below some text?

Tags: vertical-alignment

I wish to begin a statement just below some text.

e.g.

```
  This is the point . below which i wish to begin the next statement
                    I wish to start this statement from just below the dot
```

Comment: Can  you add a graphical representation of what you want?

Comment: Some context would help.  For example, is the statement added below expected to continue onto a following line, or will it be confined to a single line?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways.  The preferable one depends on the context, which has not been provided by the OP.  Also, the term "just below" the dot is a bit ambiguous, as well.

In Method I, a `tabto` approach is employed.  This has the advantage of allowing the undertext to continue to line wrap to *the beginning* of the following line. (No mention is made by the OP if hanging text is needed below the dot, for example)

Method II uses a `stackengine` approach, in which both the overtext and undertext, as currently employed, must each lie in a single line.  Other stacking options would permit a multi-line understack, if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto,stackengine}
\def\savept{\tabto*{0pt}\edef\tmp{\TabPrevPos}\tabto{\TabPrevPos}}
\def\gotopt{\tabto{\tmp}}
\begin{document}
METHOD I:

This is the point \savept. below which i wish to begin the next statement
\gotopt
I wish to start this statement from just below the dot

This is the point \savept. below which i wish to begin the next statement
that line wraps\gotopt
I wish to start this statement from just below the dot in a line that also wraps

METHOD II:

This is the point\def\stackalignment{l}\def\stacktype{L}
\stackunder{. below which i wish to begin the next statement}{%
I wish to start this statement from just below the dot}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would do this, but I am sure there is a better solution.

```
$\text{This is the point}
\ 
\text{. below which i wish to begin the next statement}$

$\phantom{\text{This is the point}}
\ 
\text{I wish to start this statement from just below the dot}$
```